# error c2065: _malloca undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, std, windows-ce

The code compiles correctly on Win32 platform, but results in following error on WinCe.

> \armv4i\stdlib.h(146): error C2065: '_malloca' : undeclared identifier
>
> on line 146 in stdlib file, compiler complains about _malloca
>
> line 146: _CRT_BANNED_DEPRECATE(_malloca and _freea) __checkReturn __bcount(_Size) void * __cdecl _alloca(__in size_t _Size);

Comment: could it be this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91128b14-bab5-40b7-91de-b3b39293ecc5/windows-embedded-compact-7-sdk-issues?forum=winembplatdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Zdeslav Vojkovic, saved me a lot of time.

All I had to do is include < stdlib.h > in every cpp file where I had the above mentioned errors. The other option would have been to comment _CRT_BANNED_DEPRECATE but I did not want to do that.
  This was a helpful link regarding this probelm:
  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91128b14-bab5-40b7-91de-b3b39293ecc5/windows-embedded-compact-7-sdk-issues?forum=winembplatdev